# Python high performance plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the problem that I need to plot and examine time series in python which are sampled at very high frequency (65000 Hz).
This results in a huge number of points and matplotlib seems doing this very slowly with a high performance computer.

I wonder if anyone has a suggestion towards an alternative.

After importing matplotlib (import matplotlib.pyplot as plt), to plot the data I just use:

```
f1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(data_frame.iloc[:,0], data_frame.iloc[:,1:])
plt.title('')
plt.xlabel(data_frame.columns[0])
plt.legend(data_frame.columns[1:])
plt.xlim([0,10])
f1.show()
```

were data_frame is a pandas data frame with 10 columns.

Thanks!!

Comment: You want to refresh a plot at 65kHz when human vision is limited to ~0.1kHz?

Comment: @Mat Err, no. The data has been sampled at 65K Hz.

Comment: I need to analyze visually the data by sliding through the plot and zooming in in different areas.

Comment: @JanusGowda Can you please `print(df.head(10))` and post it here?

Comment: The idea would be to subsample the data to visualize. I.e. only show 1000 points at once. If you zoom in, show again 1000 points but from the zoomed region. And so on.